# how to export project and all dependency in intellij idea?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, save, project

I write a android project that have many dependency. And wanna move project to another computer but move all dependency and set dependency path for another PC again, take long time.

do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Git or other version control systems will be able to do this for you. They make developing a breeze and I would recommend investing some time to learning one for situations like this.